# Change soft limit of file descriptors on Fedora

Tags: file-descriptors, ulimit

I've encountered an issue that require me to increase the max open file descriptors for Chrome. However, I did not have luck and the value seems to stuck at 1024 and I can't increase it. I'm using Fedora 37.

#### What I've done

- Added soft & hard limit into `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

  ```bash
  *     hard  nofile  80896
  *     soft  nofile  64512
  root  hard  nofile  80896
  root  soft  nofile  64512
  ```
- I checked and make sure nothing on `/etc/security/limits.d/*` cause conflict with that.
- Added this to the end of `/etc/pam.d/login`

  ```bash
  session    required     pam_limits.so
  ```
- I even added this to `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/systemd/user.conf` (But I ended up removing it again because it doesn't seems to do anything on my case)

  ```bash
  DefaultLimitNOFILE=80896
  ```
- I did reboot every time I test all of those thing I changed to make sure it's applied
- Tried to change the soft limit temporarily but it does work (temporarily)

  ```bash
  $ ulimit -Sn 64512
  ```

#### Current Condition

When I check ulimit, I still got 1024:

```bash
$ ulimit -Sn
1024

$ ulimit -Hn
80896
```

Open Chrome and check the soft limit, I got 1024:

```bash
$ cat /proc/$CHROME_PID/limits | grep -e "Max open files" -e "Limit"
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max open files            1024                 80896                files
```

However open Firefox and check it, I got 4096:

```bash
$ cat /proc/$FIREFOX_PID/limits | grep -e "Max open files" -e "Limit"
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max open files            4096                 80896                files
```

#### Question

It seems like changing the hard limit is working while soft limit seems unchanged, I don't now where the soft limit for `ulimit`, Chrome or Firefox comes from (perhaps, is there a way for me to track it? or change it for a particular app only?)

I'd like to know if I did something wrong? or are there some configuration that I need to do? I'm really confused, all of this thing is foreign to me, I never touched PAM or systemd before.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does *cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max* output ?

Comment: @MC68020 the output is: `9223372036854775807`